# .net core mocking dbcontext not working (static issue?)

Tags: c#, testing, .net-core, moq, xunit

I am trying to test .net core 2.2 api's. I am having difficulty mocking (using moq) the dbcontext. What is the syntax for adapting my mockDbContext to be usable. I receive a NullReferenceException. Since the Changetracker is never instantiated I believe. Do I need a different approach? I saw mentioned .UseInMemoryDatabase() but, with very little documentation or good examples.

Below is the code I am trying to use in my test [Fact].

```
     var mockDbContext = new Mock<dbContext>(optionsBuilder.Options);
     var controller = new HomeController(mockDbContext.object);
```

Then use controller to test... removed for brevity

```
var datafromdbcontext = controller.GetData();
```

Below is an example of my dbcontext.

```
    public class dbContext:DbContext
    {
        public dbContext(DbContextOptions<dbContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {
            //MAKE IT READONLY
            ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = 
       QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of examples of using the InMemory database (which is what you normally use for unit tests) ... Here is an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory

You shouldn't try to Mock the actual context, you use the InMemory option instead. So - your context, but with the InMemory "option"... Like so:

```
var myFakeContext = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MYDBCONTEXT>().UseInMemoryDatabase("SO-MADE-UP-NAME");
```

Comment: So I should be using .InMemoryDatabase() if I am having moq Issues?

Comment: Yes, in fact in EF Core you shouldn't mock your DbContext at all but opt for InMemoryDatabase

Comment: @Sangman beat me to it.. Yes, so, you shouldnt try to Mock the actual context, you use the InMemory option instead. So - your context, but with the InMemory "option"...

I've added the example to the answer

Comment: Yes, use InMemoryDatabase and see how far it gets you. There are a few things in-memory doesn't support. Should you need to mock a FromSql (eg, calling a stored proc), check out my example here: https://github.com/efarr/mock-ef-core-fromsql

Comment: Its true, there are limitations - it all depends how complicated you want your tests to be really.. I normally go down the route of some sort of repository pattern so that I can totally abstract away the DbContext anyway

Comment: @EricFarr, There no benefits in mocking `FromSql`, If you are using raw sql queries in your application - write tests against actual database - this tests provide much more benefits, then mocking. With tests against actual database you will be able to refactor/optimize queries and in few seconds get a feedback "did you break something"

Comment: @Fabio - It depends totally on what you're trying to test and what you're trying to achieve. Theres two different types of tests designed for different reasons.The one you're referring to is called an integration test and its fundamentally different to a unit test. Mocking typically (but not necessarily always) comes into play in "Unit Tests".

Comment: I am doing controller tests that hold my api s. I am in the repository pattern and because of my dependencies I will have to use .InMemoryDatabase to mock the controller db context. Additionally, I am not using sql I am using linq(side note). I am testing the return code for my api s and not the actual data. The issue is you have to mock the dependencies of a controller to use it in testing.

Comment: @Fabio, In my case, I was trying to add unit tests to legacy code that had a callout to a sproc in the middle of the method. Mocking FromSql was the only way to do it. BTW, I'm all for integration tests that hit a live database in addition to unit tests.

Comment: @RobertPerry, test which just checking that `FromSql` function is called produce very little feedback but bound your tests to implementation details. Purpose of all tests to verify that application works and provide safety net during refactoring. Tests can be quick or slow. Slow tests are tests which run slow(accessing external resources) or complicated to setup (requires multiple logic branches to be configured). We should mock as less as possible and every time you introduce a mock which just verifying some method is called is considered as a code smell.

Comment: A mock is a code smell? Thats the first time i’ve heard that before!

Comment: @RobertPerry, "code smell" doesn't mean is bad. Code smell si a code, which will possibly introduce more problems than benefits in a long run. By mocking all dependencies you will not be able freely refactor and change internal design, because every change will force to rewrite tests.

Comment: Are you saying you shouldn’t write mocks because it means you can’t change your code without changing a unit test?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a library, available on NuGet and GitHub called EntityFrameworkCoreMock that does the heavy lifting of setting everything up. There's also an implementation for Moq.

https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-core-mock

**Example usage**

```cs
public class User
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class MyTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var initialEntities = new[]
        {
            new User { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), FullName = "Eric Cartoon" },
            new User { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), FullName = "Billy Jewel" },
        };

        var dbContextMock = new DbContextMock<TestDbContext>(DummyOptions);
        var usersDbSetMock = dbContextMock.CreateDbSetMock(x => x.Users, initialEntities);

        // Pass dbContextMock.Object to the class/method you want to test

        // Query dbContextMock.Object.Users to see if certain users were added or removed
        // or use Mock Verify functionality to verify if certain methods were called: usersDbSetMock.Verify(x => x.Add(...), Times.Once);
   }

    public DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> DummyOptions { get; } = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestDbContext>().Options;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can Mock DbContext like this :

source (Synchronous/Asynchronous): https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking?redirectedfrom=MSDN

```
            var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<User>>();
            mockSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<User>>()
              .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator())
              .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<User>(data.GetEnumerator()));

            mockSet.As<IQueryable<User>>()
               .Setup(m => m.Provider)
               .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<User>(data.Provider));

            mockSet.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => data.GetEnumerator());

            var mockContext = new Mock<IWebApiDbContext>();
            mockContext.Setup(m => m.User).ReturnsDbSet(mockSet.Object);
```

But you will cannot alterate(**Add/Delete/Update**) the data. Only Get them.

so the solution can be Use in Memory :

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<WebApiDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "dbContext")
                .Options;

            var context = new WebApiDbContext(options);
```